# How to make a dotted underline link on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a link `<a class="link-articles" href="#articles">My Articles</a>`

and my css `.link-articles { text-decoration: underline; color: blue; }`

However, on hover I would like to have instead of blue underline a red underline, but the text should remain blue and only the underscore change color to red.

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you cannot denote <del>which color</del> a second color for the text underline, one strategy is to remove it and use a border.

```
.link-articles
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link-articles:hover
{
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

Note that if you leave the `text-underline`, it will shift down when hovering, since it's placement is not exactly the same location as the bottom border.

This approach has an added advantage of being able to <strike>position the underline by using `line-height` and</strike> have alternate line styles, by replacing `solid` with `dotted` or `dashed`.

**Borderless Approach:**

As @Pacerier points out in the comments, here is an alternate strategy using pseudo-classes and CSS content ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ws5gc0r3/1/)):

```
.link-articles
{
    position: relative;
}

.link-articles[href="#articles"]:after
{
    content: 'My Articles';
}

.link-articles:after
{
    color: red;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

However, with anti-aliasing, it may have some color-blending on the text edges. If you don't like the thought of having to manually put `content` in your CSS, you could use an attribute or duplicate element.

Comment: We **can** specify the color of the text underline since it will be the same as the color of the text. To have two different color for the font and underline, we need to **overlay** a new text above it, such that the old text color is covered by the new text color.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Pacerier. I've updated my answer to include an approach using text overlays. Personally, I like the border approach because you can fine-tune the positioning of it using `line-height`, and using different border styles like `dotted`.

Comment: How exactly can the position of the line be controlled using `line-height`? When I test in Safari, the distance of the line from the text is not affected. A larger line-height than the surrounding text just increases the space to the next line. A smaller line-height has no effect at all. The distance of the border from the text never changes. Perhaps it works in other browsers, but then it is only useful in controlled environments like intranets.

Comment: @OttoG You are absolutely correct. That is a mistake on my part and I apologize for any confusion. The `line-height` property has no bearing on the underline. A `padding-bottom` attribute can help, but I will remove that verbiage from the answer so no one else wonders. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @OttoG On second thought, I think the `line-height` property does work, but only if the link's `display` is set to `inline-block`. Regardless, it is a bit confusing and doesn't add to the answer of the OP, so I will omit it for now.

Answer (score 9):

Just do:

```
a:hover {
  text-decoration-style: dotted
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style

Answer (score 8):

Use `border-bottom`:

```
a:hover.link-articles {border-bottom: 1px dotted red; text-decoration: none;}
```

[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nKqCD/)

Answer (score 3):

Use a border:

```
.link-articles { text-decoration: none; border-bottom: blue 1px solid; }
.link-articles:hover { border-bottom: red 1px dotted; }
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/nKqCD/3/)

```
.link-articles { text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted blue; }
.link-articles:hover { text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 .link-articles{ text-decoration: none; border-bottom:1px dotted; border-color:blue; }
 .link-articles:hover{ border-color:red; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nKqCD/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Show bottom border on hover:

```
a.link-articles {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
}
a.link-articles:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage to this approach is the underline will "shift" down when hovered. jsfiddle.net/4dKFu

Comment: I Solved that problem by making transparent bottom border. http://jsfiddle.net/4dKFu/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `:hover` style is used to set style when user places mouse over element.

```
.link-articles       { ... }
.link-articles:hover { ... }
```

And you can use the `border-bottom` property instead of `text-decoration` for dotted, dashed and width styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 `text-decoration-color` property, but unfortunatly, the `text-decoration-color` property is not supported in any of the major browsers.

Firefox supports an alternative, the `-moz-text-decoration-color` property.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp

Browser Support: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/pjrkcosq/) (Doesn't works on all browsers)

So the best way to do that is still to use the `border-bottom` css property as a trick.